# Why am I not able to apply the update KB3033929 on my Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I get this error when trying to install KB3033929:

[image]

**Steps tried:**

1. I have tried this command: `wusa.exe c:\934307\Windows6.1-KB3033929-x86.msu`
2. I confirmed that my computer is Windows 7 32-bit:
3. The sfc /scannow on Adminstrator Priveleges cmd

[image: Computer Specification]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says, it's not applicable to your operating system. You either have the wrong version for your OS (bit level/architecture), are missing prerequisites, already have it installed, or you have an update installed that replaced/superseded that update (making this one no longer applicable).

In your case I believe you're missing a prerequisite, Service Pack 1.

According to the [KB itself](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3033929):

> Applies to:
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1, Windows 7 **Service Pack 1**

According to the System info image you posted, you don't have Service Pack 1 installed.  If you did, it would be noted on that screen:

[image]

So you'll need to install [Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842) before that update can be applied.

Comment: so u mean i need service pack 1 and the update would work ?

Comment: Yes, install SP1, and then try the update again.

Comment: could u pls provide me the Link for service pack 1 windows 7 32 bit thanks in advance

Comment: You can Google it, or search Microsoft's site, or just look at the last line of my answer. ;)

Comment: i got it https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842 but it contain 4-5 which should i  use  @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007?

Comment: @AkhilJain It kinda says if you check the install instructions on that very page.

Comment: Why aren't you just using Windows Update to do this (it'll figure all that out for you)?  Anyhow, read the "Install Instructions" on the page, it tells you what you need (grab the ISO to start).

Comment: last line contains KB3033929  link not SP1 pls tell me which should i download in 4-5 files    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842

Comment: Fixed the link to SP1, and you've already been told what to download and told how to determine it on your own.  This isn't "Hold my hand and help me fix my problem step by step.com".  ;)   If you have more/different questions, please post them as such.

Comment: thanks for the help :) sorry for the trouble i am a rookie in trouble shooting

Comment: One other thing to note in addition to the SP1 is the Windows 7 rollup update. This will get your machine to a certain time period in Windows Update history, allowing for easier/quicker updates in the future.

Comment: I have sp1 but can't run this.